# MS-SQL on Ubuntu: unable to restore database.bak file

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu-16.04, database-restore

I am not able to restore a database backup (db.bak).

Given the following Transact-SQL:

```
1> RESTORE DATABASE db
2> FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/db.bak' ;
3> GO
```

Results in:

```
Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Server mbü-lubuntu, Line 1
Directory lookup for the file "D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER2014\MSSQL\DATA\db.mdf" failed with the operating     
system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Server mbü-lubuntu, Line 1
File 'db' cannot be restored to 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER2014\MSSQL\DATA\db.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to     
identify a valid location for the file.
Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Server mbü-lubuntu, Line 1
Directory lookup for the file "D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER2014\MSSQL\DATA\db_log.ldf" failed with the     
operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Server mbü-lubuntu, Line 1
File 'db_log' cannot be restored to 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER2014\MSSQL\DATA\db_log.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to     
identify a valid location for the file.
Msg 3119, Level 16, State 1, Server mbü-lubuntu, Line 1
Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous 
messages provide details.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server mbü-lubuntu, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

I am even wondering, why the agent is looking for a Windows Path (D:\Program Files...) in a Linux program?

/var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf:

```
[EULA]
accepteula = Y

[sqlagent]
enabled = true

[filelocation]
defaultbackupdir = /var/opt/mssql/data/
defaultdatadir = /var/opt/mssql/data/
defaultdumpdir = /var/opt/mssql/data/
defaultlogdir = /var/opt/mssql/data/
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because the database was created and backed up on Windows. The database remembers where it came from, and tries to restore to the same place.

You probably need to use the `WITH MOVE` clause of the [restore statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql#restoring_db_n_move_files), as the error message points out.

Answer (score 3):

Kirchner is right. Your error spells this out:

"File 'db_log' cannot be restored to 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER2014\MSSQL\DATA\db_log.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to
identify a valid location for the file."

Here's what the restore command will look like:

```
USE [master];
GO
RESTORE DATABASE [db] FROM DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/db.bak'
WITH MOVE '<file_name>' TO '<file_location>'
, MOVE '<file_name>' TO '<file_location>'
...;
GO
```

Assuming you have a directory `/data/`, the database has two files (one data file and one log file). The following is the statement in practice:

```
USE [master];
GO
RESTORE DATABASE [db] FROM DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/db.bak'
WITH MOVE 'db' TO '/data/db.mdf'
, MOVE 'db_log' TO '/data/db_log.ldf'
...;
GO
```

Remember Linux is case sensitive. If you have no idea where you can put the log and data file. Stick it in the same place as the files for the master database (exec sp_helpdb 'master').

Love and Kisses,
A-

Answer (score 0):

By default, MS SQL Server assumes that the file path(s) specified in the dbname.bak file indicate where the database should be restored. If these file path(s) do not exist, you will encounter an error similar to the one mentioned.

To resolve this, you can explicitly instruct the database to use different file(s). However, before proceeding, it is important to determine how the file(s) are referenced by executing the following T-SQL command:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '/path/to/dbname.bak'
```

This command will provide you with information such as:

```
Dbname_Empty
Dbname_Empty_log
```

You can then utilize this information to execute the following T-SQL command, ensuring a successful restoration without encountering any errors:

```
RESTORE DATABASE dbname
FROM DISK = '/path/to/dbname.bak'
WITH MOVE 'Dbname_Empty' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/dbname.mdf',
MOVE 'Dbname_Empty_log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/dbname.ldf'
```